# Which philosopher is most famous for his view on academic freedom, and in which text?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, freedom

Which philosopher is most famous for his view on academic freedom, and in which text? I am looking for particular texts on academic freedom.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different philosophers who have written about academic freedom, but the most famous is probably John Stuart Mill. In his text On Liberty, Mill argues that individuals should be free to pursue knowledge and truth as they see fit, without interference from the government or other authority figures. This means that people should be able to freely discuss and debate ideas, without fear of punishment or retribution. This view of academic freedom is still very influential today.